# iOS 10 Notification Service Extension

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios10, nsnotificationcenter

I'm working on the iOS 10 APNs function, trying to add Notification Service Extension to an existing App, add the function of pushing an image to the App.

After the extension was added, it did receive the pushed message. But couldn't receive the image, the function(wrote in the extension) of downloading the pushed image didn't execute during debugging. I checked the content in the App package, confirmed that the extension was installed in the App, it just didn't work.

What made me confused was that: I built a new testing project with same bundle id. The testing app could receive the pushed message and show the image correctly.(please see below screen shot)

What's wrong with the existing project? I tried to find the difference between the existing project and the testing project, yet found nothing in the code, setting, environment.

Does anyone encountered this before? I have been struggling in this for a week...

[image: screen shot]

reference:

WWDC 2016 APNS Guide: https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/wwdc-2016-rich-notifications-in-ios-10

Apple notification guide:https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH16-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this bug was fixed, please see the attached image. XCode recommends setting the architecture as automatic and I did so, then the notification service extension worked and could receive the pushed image. I don't know why this setting caused the problem, but I'm sure it works.

[image]